# Insert ' ' to every integer that is found in txt format

Tags: awk, sed

I have a huge amount of data with the next format and I want to insert '' to each number found.

Input:

```
   202, "Pen"  ,
   203, "Unassigned"  ,
   204, "Pencil"  ,
   205, "Scissor"  ,
   206, "Mouse"  ,
   207, "Unassigned"  ,
   208, "Laptopn"  ,
   209, "Unassigned"  ,
   210, "Unassigned"  ,
```

Expected Output:

```
   '202', "Pen"  ,
   '203', "Unassigned"  ,
   '204', "Pencil"  ,
   '205', "Scissor"  ,
   '206', "Mouse"  ,
   '207', "Unassigned"  ,
   '208', "Laptopn"  ,
   '209', "Unassigned"  ,
   '210', "Unassigned"  ,
```

What I'm doing is the next:

```
awk   ' { for ( i = 1; i <= NF; ++i ) {
    if ( $i == int )
        r = 1        
  }
}1 ' example.txt > example2.txt
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw).

Comment: I'm new on this, thanks for your comment btw @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Your code isn't checking whether the field is an integer; it is checking if it is equal to the undeclared variable `int` (so effectively checking if it is equal to the empty string or zero).

Comment: I believe this question should be re-opened, since OP has added efforts in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested exactly based on your shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
($1~/^[0-9]+,$/){
   $1="\047"$1
   sub(/,$/,"\047&",$1)
}
1
' Input_file
```

OR in case you have multiple fields where you need to convert all field's starting from digits wrapped with `'` then try following.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^[0-9]+,$/){
      $i="\047"$i
      sub(/,$/,"\047&",$i)
    }
  }
}
1
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above. Explanation for 1st and 2nd solution are same, only difference between these 2 are 1st one is specific to 1st field in terms of substitution and 2nd solution goes through all fields to perform substitution.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){         ##Traversing through all fields of current line here.
    if($i~/^[0-9]+,$/){       ##Checking condition if current field starts from digits(continously) and ends with a comma then do following.
      $i="\047"$i             ##Adding single quote before current field then.
      sub(/,$/,"\047&",$i)    ##Substituting comma(comint at last of field) with single quote and comma in current field.
    }
  }
}
1                             ##1 will print current line here.
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Great! That's work as expected, could you explain a little bit?

Comment: @Luka, have added detailed explanation for solutions now, cheers.

Comment: @Luka, Also I hope your actual Input_file is same as shown samples, where comma is coming after digits, because my solutions are dealing with it, let me now if any queries here.

Comment: One more question that I forgot, How could I change the fisrt comma in ecah field for ''':''' so would receive 

'202':"Pen"  ,
'203': "Unassigned"  ,

Comment: @Luka, just change `sub(/,$/,"\047&",$1)` TO `sub(/,$/,"\047:",$1)` in first solution AND change from `sub(/,$/,"\047&",$i)` TO `sub(/,$/,"\047:",$i)` in above solutions and we should be all set.

Comment: One last thing @RavinderSingh13. Imagine that instead having '202' I have '20201': 'Pen' and I want to erase the four digit if it is a zero. How would you do it?

Comment: @Luka, hello Luka, I am sorry but it looks to me a new question here, totally different from here. IMHO I would like to request you to please open a new question along with your efforts, so that we all get better understanding of question and could help and guide, I hope you understand, questions in comments are not encouraged on SO, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226035/discussion-between-luka-and-ravindersingh13).